# A case of indirect indexing

Tags: r, indexing

Here's a table with four columns filled with numerical values and a fifth column filled with column names.
The desired result is to calculate column R so that :
for row 1, the result is the first value in column D (D being the value in the first row of column NC)
for row 2, the result is the second value in column A (A being the value in the second row of column NC)
and so on for all the rows in the example.

I've tried so many different approaches that I can't summarize them here.
How do I calculate column R correctly?

```
A | B | C | D  | NC| R 
9 | 5 | 5 | 10 | D | 10 
4 | 10 | 5 | 6 | A | 4
```

```
set.seed(1)
example <- data.frame(U = seq(10))
example %>%  mutate(A = sample(10,10,replace = TRUE), B = sample(10,10,replace = TRUE), C = sample(10,10,replace = TRUE), D= sample(10,10,replace = TRUE),NC = sample(c("A","B","C","D"),10,replace = TRUE) ) %>% select(A,B,C,D, NC) -> example
```

I've tried so many different approaches that I can't summarize them here.
How do I calculate column R correctly?

I do have a solution, but it uses a for loop, and I'd like to do without one. Here's the code that gives a solution:

```
for(i in 1:dim(example)[1]) { example$R[i] <- example[[example$NC[i]]][i] }
```

This solution may be slow. Is it possible to do better?

Answer (score 4):

`example$NC` contains column names, so `example[example$NC]` will return  a data frame of those columns in the order they appear in `example$NC`.

You want the first value from column 1, the second value from column 2 and so on. This means you can just convert the data frame to a matrix and take the [`diag()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diag.html) of that:

```r
example$R  <- diag(as.matrix(example[example$NC]))
```

This gives the same output as your loop:

```r
example
#    A  B  C  D NC  R
# 1  9  5  5 10  D 10
# 2  4 10  5  6  A  4
# 3  7  6  2  4  C  2
# 4  1 10 10  4  D  4
# 5  2  7  9 10  B  7
# 6  7  9  1  9  B  9
# 7  2  5  4  7  C  4
# 8  3  5  3  6  C  3
# 9  1  9  6  9  B  9
# 10 5  9 10  8  B  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
example %>%
    mutate(R = .[cbind(seq_len(n()), match(NC, names(.)))])
```

which gives

```
   A  B  C  D NC  R
1  9  5  5 10  D 10
2  4 10  5  6  A  4
3  7  6  2  4  C  2
4  1 10 10  4  D  4
5  2  7  9 10  B  7
6  7  9  1  9  B  9
7  2  5  4  7  C  4
8  3  5  3  6  C  3
9  1  9  6  9  B  9
10 5  9 10  8  B  9
```